# creating user in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, sql-grant

In **MySQL** command line client after logging in as root, I typed:

```
connect mydb;
grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
```

Now within **Java**,
I succesfully connect to the db using the admin userid using drivers.

```
 Statement put=connect.createStatement();

 //**WORKS succesfully**
 put.execute("insert into mydb.emp values(100,joe)");   

 //**does NOT work**
 put.execute("grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'john'@'localhost' identified by 'pass'");
```

Why does an insert command work but grant command never work through Java?

Please help.

Comment: One thing that I see immediately is that your INSERT query is a string, while your GRANT query is not.

Comment: @Xperiaz X as root you mean from linux terminal for example?

Comment: Not all databases support DDL commands via JDBC, so you might not be able to modify the database structure via JDBC at all.

Comment: no to enter sql command line client in windows we need to enter a root password. MySQL root not linux root.

Comment: Does MySQL support DDL?
or a new driver is required?

Comment: I just checked.
DDL commands like "create" are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
put.execute(MySQL query)
```

in here you can execute only MySQL query but

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';
```

Not a MySQL query it is just a command for MySQL.

Comment: Oh, I see.
So is it possible to send commands to MySQL via java?

Comment: You have to set user privileges via MySQL admin terminal(command line)

Comment: Is it not possible using java?
My application is adding an employee (thus adding a DB user). The employee then has access to other tables in the database

Comment: You can't set privileges via java for MySQL user.

Comment: Yes, finally I implemented it.
for my program ,we can set all privileges except grant option via java as long as we have root id and password.

Anyway this answer really helped me a lot.
Thank you :)

Comment: perhaps have a procedure and pass parameters then run it to create the user e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962145/944593 am trying this out my self

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the quotation marks.

Comment: My bad, In the code I had put quotation but here I forgot to type it

Comment: @XperiazX in that case you should look my answer. Check the ExtendedAnsiSQL flag

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
put.execute("grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'john'@'localhost' identified by 'pass'");
```

And also make sure you have ExtendedAnsiSQL flag to 1.

Comment: Sorry,In the code I had put quotation but here I forgot to type it here.
ExtendedAnsiSQL flag? please do tell what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I tried working with query parameters - what I found somewhat confusing is that you have to put a blank between the parameter and @localhost for example - this here worked for me: (jpaEm is a JpaEntityManager here)

```
// Create user
String sql = "CREATE USER ? @localhost";
Query query = jpaEm.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, user.getUserName());
jpaEm.getTransaction().begin();
query.executeUpdate();
jpaEm.getTransaction().commit();

// Set password
sql = "SET PASSWORD FOR ? @localhost = PASSWORD(?)";
query = jpaEm.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, user.getUserName()); 
query.setParameter(2, user.getPassword());
jpaEm.getTransaction().begin();
query.executeUpdate();
jpaEm.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe this can help someone so far. I resolved it with this code below.

   ```
    String db = "data";
    String us = "Luis";
    String pas = "123456";
    //-----Connection to the server------------
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    cntConnec = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///","admin","admin");
    Statement stmMysql = cntConnec.createStatement();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful Connection");
    //-------Create a new DB------------
    stmMysql.execute("CREATE DATABASE "+db);
    stmMysql.execute("USE "+db);
    stmMysql.execute("CREATE TABLE bobo_table (f00 char(31))");
    //-------Create a user with all privileges--------------
    stmMysql.executeUpdate("CREATE USER "+us+"@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 
                   '"+pas+"'");
    stmMysql.executeUpdate("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "+db+".* TO 
                   "+us+"@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION");
    stmMysql.executeUpdate("FLUSH PRIVILEGES");
    stmMysql.close();
   ```