# MySQL how to use stored procedures to create database users?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a stored procedure that allows people to create new database users.

I've looked up on the Internet and it seems that the only answer I find is too complex ([MySQL Stored Procedure to create user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944785/mysql-stored-procedure-to-create-user))

This is what I have, but it is not working. MySQL complains about 'psw'.

```
create procedure create_user(IN name varchar(50), IN psw varchar(50))
begin

create user name identified by psw;

end
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to implement the procedure following the logic of the one I presented, and if so, how it is done

Comment: That linked procedure only looks complex because it has to build strings of SQL to execute which there is no way around, you cannot do it "in line" as your attempting.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it then

Comment: @AlexK. I have created a stored procedure like the one linked on my post. But when I try to run it, I get the following error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_password' at line 1".Why is this happening?