# JAVA MYSQL user privilages

Tags: java, mysql

My question is related to this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567981/creating-user-in-mysql-using-java)

I need to create user, and grant him privilages to database.

Creat user works fine, but granting him privilages is pain in the ***...

I looked all around net to find anything that would help me...but have failed to fine anything but this here...

so if any1 knows what I'm doing wrong (i understand that GRANT dosent work with java, but Xperiaz X said that he figured it out...) and how I can grant trough Java I would be very gratefull

```
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int Result=st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE createtest2");
        Result = st.executeUpdate("CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `createtest2`.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';");
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Statement#executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)), we can only execute MySql query but `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'createtest2'.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';` is not mysql query.

But it's just a command in mysql so you can't do this using statement in java. In case, if you want to do it in java, then you should look at [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) api of java.

Comment: I know it's a command, but i dont know how to execute that comand from my program...

Comment: ok, so I listened to your advice and did folowing "Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
               rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","mysql -u root -ptest123","CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';"});
               
            } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("nije uspjelo");
            }"

Comment: i did folowing <code>Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
               rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","mysql -u root -ptest123","CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';"});
               
            } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("nije uspjelo");
            }</code>  but does not create user in my db. What did I do wrong??