# Getting error in executeUpdate Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I trying to set "ALL PRIVILEGES" from Java on remote MySQL database `test` and user `test` . Here is snippet of my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = null;
con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/?user=root&password=pswrd");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
int res = st.executeUpdate("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';");
```

Nothing extraordinary. All queries from root user work fine, but in this partucular case I'm getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main"   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'test'
```

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17568222/1912193). So, the problem wasn't solved ...

Comment: How come the user name reads 'root'@'%'?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try establishing connection with

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that 'root@yourHost' (especially from yourHost) indentified by 'pswrd' has rights to manage privileges on this database.

Answer (score 0):

try adding host like this 'test'@'**yourhost**'

Comment: A little explanation would improve the quality of your answer.